# how to prevent listview selection item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, android-adapter

i have a listview item which looks like below. out of these countries and Food are the two headers followed by a divider. in the adapter i have written code when to show and hide the header of listview item. My list item xml comprises of

```
1) Textview --  for showing header
2) view --- for showing divider
3) Textview --- to display country/food name
```

(My listview looks like below)

```
    Countries
    -------------------------
    aaa
    bbb
    ccc

    Food
    -------------------------
    ddd
    eee
    fff
```

Here if i tap on first item, the blue color selection happens for full item i.e for header, divider and country name, but for second item onwards it looks ok. Similarly if i tap on first item of Food, again the header,divider & food item is getting selected.

I want only country or food filed needs to be selected, how to suppress selection color on divider & header text

Comment: can you post your code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the individual names to be selected by themselves, they need to each be individual list items. Similarly, you can control which items can be selected, but it's much harder to make only some parts of a list item selectable.

I recommend you watch [The World of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&ei=nldLU_SRO8Sa8AGPt4GABQ&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=Q92fBwyd_NEWmfSgHr3SkQ) and pay close attention to the part about using different View types in your ListView. In your list adapter, you can define headers and content to have different types and determine which items can be selected based on this type. The relevant methods are `getItemViewType()` and `getItemViewTypeCount()`.

Comment: can u please provide any sample examples which fulfill my above requirements

Comment: in the example you have provided, he is using 2 different types of views. but i'm trying to achieve the same using single view based on hide and show logic. Also i'm using cursor it returns from db & passing the same to cursoradapter, if i need to show two extra items which are not part of cursor at the first position how to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
how to prevent listview selection item
```

You need to disable all the click listener to that `Section Header`.

Assume `v` is section Header so disable like

```
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

v.setOnClickListener(null);
v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
v.setLongClickable(false);
```

For more details go through [Section ListView](http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-section-listview.html)

You will find a way to do this.

Comment: hi amit, i dont want to see that blue color text to when i tap on divider or diver title. is your code doing the same?

Comment: @Naruto go through the sample first , you will find a way. Then you can according to ur requirement.

Comment: Amit thank you, i will check and revert back. Also one more thing i would like to say is i use cursor adapter, in which data comes from DB, and i want to print 2 items at the first position but they are not part of cursor and remaining as usual cursor data i need to display